# Android RelativeLayout with a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

Here's what I'm trying to do :
[image: goal]

My code :

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/paf"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/brightnessSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/paf" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/localization" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that the fragment fills it all with "match_parent" but gets tiny with "wrap_content"
I already tried the width="0dp" shown on the android official guide

Comment: size of fragment is 50dp?

Comment: I don't know, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Try this

[image]

*Increase space's **layout_width** if you want more space between them.*

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />

    <Space
        android:id="@+id/brightnessSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/paf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/brightnessSeekBar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<Space
    android:id="@+id/brightnessSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageView"/>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/paf"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/brightnessSeekBar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```